# Send content over the network to client without client being able to extract the content to their local machine

Tags: http, web, networking, http-headers, media-queries

Is it possible to send content over the network to client without client being able to extract the content to their local machine?

I mean what if someone decides to sell media content using browsers, then once someone gets hold of the content he or she is able to go to **Chrome Inspect** - **Network** and just download the content to their local machine, which would enable them to spread the content for free later on (while initially the access to the content was provided just for someone who is authenticated for the site serving the content and paid for the content).

Are there any headers maybe which would prohibit doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking how to do effective DRM, which is well-known to be impossible. Think about it from this perspective: if what you're describing were possible, Hollywood would do it and there'd be no such thing as movie piracy.

Comment: Great. Thank you. The DRM related literature is what I was looking for.